# Can we just see the Hex code without preview in hexl-mode?

Tags: hexl-mode

I would like to use the `hexl-mode` but without the ASCII characters printed on the right side as it is mostly gibberish and not a very helpful feature for me. Is there a way to achieve that?

For example:

```
00000000: 4672 6564 7269 636b 0000 0000 0000 0000  Fredrick........
```

Needs to be simply:

```
00000000: 4672 6564 7269 636b 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: Anything to do with `hexl-follow-ascii`?

Comment: No `hexl-follow-ascii` just controls the highlighting of the character corresponding to the current point-position. I had a look at [hexl](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lib-src/hexl.c). There is no option for that workhorse that avoids the ascii string. My first simple approach would be to set the foreground equal to the background in `hexl-ascii-region`.

Comment: @Tobias, You can move this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following elisp code defines a new minor mode `hexl-bin-mode` that replaces the ascii-region with spaces. That should avoid side-effects caused by faces as they may appear in my first answer.

You can switch on the binary hexl mode by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `hexl-bin-mode` or bind the command `hexl-bin-mode` to any key you want with `local-set-key` in `hexl-mode-hook`.

```el
(require 'hexl)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Make hexlify-buffer more versatile by adding a hook.
(defvar hexlify-hook nil
  "Hook run after `hexlify-buffer'.")

(defun hexlify-hook (&rest _args) ;; For the case that the argument list of `hexlify-buffer' changes in future.
  "Run functions registered at `hexlify-hook'."
  (run-hooks 'hexlify-hook))

(advice-add 'hexlify-buffer :after #'hexlify-hook)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Define minor-mode for supporting `hexlify-remove-ascii-region'.

(defun hexlify-remove-ascii-region (&rest _args)
  "Remove ASCII region generated by `hexlify-buffer'."
  ;; We cannot use `delete-rectangle' because there may be incomplete lines.
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((start (1- (hexl-ascii-start-column))))
      (while
          (progn
            (forward-char start) 
            (replace-region (point) (line-end-position)
                            (make-string (- (line-end-position) (point)) ?\s))
            (and (eq (forward-line) 0)
                 (null (eobp))))))))

(defun hexl-refresh ()
  "Refresh hexl buffer after manipulation of ascii-region"
  (let ((pt (point))
        buffer-undo-list) ; prevents query of `dehexlify-buffer'
    (dehexlify-buffer)
    (hexlify-buffer)
    (goto-char pt)))

(define-minor-mode hexl-bin-mode
  "Don't show ascii region."
  nil " B" nil
  (if hexl-bin-mode
      (progn
        (cl-assert (derived-mode-p 'hexl-mode) nil
                   "hexl-bin-mode only available for hexl-mode")
        (add-hook 'hexlify-hook #'hexlify-remove-ascii-region nil t)
        (hexl-refresh))
    (remove-hook 'hexlify-hook #'hexlify-remove-ascii-region t)
    (when (derived-mode-p 'hexl-mode)
      (hexl-refresh))))

(defun hexl-insert-char-ignore (oldfun ch num)
  "Ignore `hexl-insert-char' in `hexl-bin-mode'."
  (if hexl-bin-mode
      (let ((address (hexl-current-address t)))
        (while (> num 0)
          (let ((hex-position (hexl-address-to-marker address))
                (ascii-position
                 (+ (* (/ address 16) (hexl-line-displen))
                    (hexl-ascii-start-column)
                    (point-min)
                    (% address 16)))
                at-ascii-position)
            (if (= (point) ascii-position)
                (setq at-ascii-position t))
            (goto-char hex-position)
            (delete-char 2)
            (insert (format "%02x" ch))
            (setq num (1- num)))))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(advice-add 'hexl-insert-char :around #'hexl-insert-char-ignore)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, I will check it out tomorrow and update you. I am not in front of my Emacs now.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to hide the ascii-part of the hexl buffer is customizing the foreground of the face `hexl-ascii-region` to the background value (e.g., `white`).

For using this method make sure that `font-lock-mode` is active in the `hexl-mode`. It may be that you need

`(add-hook 'hexl-mode-hook #'font-lock-mode)`

in your init-file.

Comment: That way the ASCII-region will still be marked, if multiple lines are selected, though

Comment: @kai-dj Yes. I know. Now you can decide whether this is a bug or a feature;-).